# Comment faire référence au chat qui sort habituellement de la maison ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, zoologie

Il y a des chats qui sortent régulièrement de la maison ainsi que des chats qui ne sortent pas de la maison. En anglais, on appelle le premier un ***outdoor cat*** et l'autre un ***indoor cat***.

Comment y fait-on référence en français ?

J'ai consulté mes dictionnaires, linguee, et wordreference, mais je ne peux pas le trouver.

---

There are cats that regularly leave the house as well as chats that do not leave the house. In English, we call the former an ***outdoor cat*** and the latter an ***indoor cat***.

**How do you refer to these two types of cats in French?**

I consulted my dictionaries, linguee, and wordreference, but I did not find anything.

Comment: @Laure Comments are ephemeral by design and are not meant to contain answers. If you have an answer to the question, you should post it as such, even if it's short or simple to you. All the more power to you if you get reputation without putting hours of effort into it. Would you rather someone else posted your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Kareen Comments are ephemeral, I agree but I think online dictionaries will always exist. I do think upvotes should go to elaborate and instructive answers. Poor answers don't do credit neither to the site nor to the posters.

Comment: @Laure Simple questions will often get simple answers. Simple doesn't mean poor. Yes dictionaries will always exist, but, like in this instance, don't always come through. They don't often contain expressions. That's where we come in. Posting in the right place also allows for the voting system to kick in and avoid lengthy discussions below the question that don't pertain to the question itself. I thank you for posting an answer though!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En France (je ne sais pas pour les autres pays francophones) on parle de **chats d'intérieur** (ou chats d'appartements) et de **chats d'extérieur**. Quand un chat vit toujours à l'extérieur et n'a pas de maître on parle de chat errant.
Par exemple [un blog sur les chats](http://sensibilisationdeschats.blogspot.fr/p/le-chat-dexterieur-plus-heureux-que-le.html).

En réponse à la question de @Onaeu :

À l'origine  « chat de gouttière » désignait un chat d'extérieur (plutôt citadin, l'expression est parisienne) ainsi nommé parce que les chats aiment se promener sur les toits. La pente du toit étant plutôt inconfortable pour un séjour prolongé, la gouttière est la partie du toit privilégiée pour se reposer ou pour s'accoupler.
Désormais l'expression ne fait plus référence au mode de vie du chat mais à sa race, c'est un chat qui n'a pas de pedigree, il peut en théorie être d'intérieur comme d'extérieur. Le glissement est logique : les chats nés de ces accouplements furtifs dans les hauteurs ne peuvent pas afficher leur filiation du côté paternel.
Ceci dit un chat de gouttière sera plus facilement un chat d'extérieur que d'intérieur parce que son maître le laissera plus facilement sortir de la maison qu'un chat de race qui a une valeur monétaire plus ou moins élevée et qui peut donc devenir objet de convoitise pour quelqu'un de mal intentionné.
Un chat de gouttière peut devenir un chat errant s'il n'a pas/plus de maître.

Le chat de gouttière est aussi appelé « chat de maison ». Il ne faut donc pas confondre les appellations « chat d'appartement » qui réfère au mode de vie et « chat de maison » qui réfère à l'absence de pedigree.

Comment: ref.: _Chat de gouttière_, c'est davantage d'extérieur ou errant pour vous ? Merci, c'est bien intéressant, sans doute digne d'une réponse à part entière pour une question que j'aurais peut-être dû poser ailleurs qu'en commentaire...

Comment: Le terme "de gouttière" est passé de chat errant à "bâtard de race indéterminée" au fil des ans. Par contre, aujourd'hui, pour ne pas froisser les maître, il semble que le terme politiquement correct pour les chats de gouttière soit "Européen", dixit une amie toiletteuse.

Comment: @MakorDal Le chat européen (ou European shorthair) est un chat de race avec pedigree reconnu par la Fédération internationale féline  qu'il ne faut surtout pas confondre avec le chat de gouttière. [« Le néophyte a tendance à confondre Européen et chat de gouttière. »]( http://www.santevet.com/articles/chat-de-race-ou-gouttiere-quelle-difference#sthash.nNt7hj58.dpuf). Les Européens ont un pedigree et peuvent concourir dans les expositions félines. [L'histoire du chat Européen sur Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_shorthair).

Comment: Donc dire d'un chat de gouttière que c'est un Européen flatte peut-être l’ego de certains, mais ce n'est pas scientifique.

Comment: @Laure Je suis d'accord, d'où ma mention de "politiquement correct". Quand à la science derrière les races de chats / chien... Etant donné que les critères pour déterminer si un animal est de race ou non sont partiellement subjectif (j'ai des exemples anecdotiques dans ce sens), on est dans le flou artistique.

Comment: Ne parle-t'on pas de chat de salon pour un chat vivant exclusivement en intérieur ?

Comment: @Kii je pense que "chat de salon" peut être mal interprété, car "salon" désigne aussi un événement où on "expose". Un chat de salon pourrait donc être un chat qui fait des concours de beauté ou autre...

Comment: @Random Et surtout « chat de salon », même si compris pour un chat qui ne sort jamais est réservé pour des chats de race. Un chat d'intérieur peut être de race ou non.

Answer (score 2):

On ne les nommes pas. Mais on reconnaît que certains sont "vagabonds" alors que d'autres sont plus "casaniers".